# what is the correct time complexity of this function?

Tags: c, time-complexity

what my function does -> Given K sorted arrays arranged in form of a matrix. The task is to merge them. You need to complete mergeKArrays() function which takes 2 arguments, an arr[k][k] 2D Matrix containing k sorted arrays and an integer k denoting the number of sorted arrays. The function should return a pointer to the merged sorted arrays.

```
int *mergeKArrays(int arr[][N], int k)
{

// int *merged = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * k * k);
// do merge sort, as individual are already sorted
// just need to merge the arrays 
int *a = arr[0];
int size_c = 2 * k;
int nb = k;
int na = k;
int *b;
int *c;
int ia, ib, ic;
for(int i = 1; i <= k - 1; ++i)
{
    // merge(x, arr[i], k * i, k)
    b = arr[i];
    c = malloc(sizeof(int) * size_c);
    if(c == NULL) exit(0);
    ia = ib = ic = 0;
    while(ia < na && ib < nb)
    {
        if(a[ia] < b[ib])
        {
            c[ic++] = a[ia++];
        }
        else
        {
            c[ic++] = b[ib++];
        }  
    }
    if(ia != na)
    {
        for(int i = ia; i < na; ++i)
        {
            c[ic++] = a[i];
        }
    }
    if(ib != nb)
    {
        for(int i = ib; i < nb; ++i)
        {
            c[ic++] = b[i];
        }
    }
    a = c;
    na = size_c;
    // printArray(a, na);
    // printf("\n");
    size_c = size_c + k;
}

return a;
}
```

- my approach : the for loop runs x = (k-1)times....
- each time array of size k is merged with i*k size array...(k+k) + (2k + k) + ....x times
- = (k + k +...x times) +(k + 1k + 2k ....x times) = kx + kx(x-1)/2
- which gives O(k^3). is this right ?
- the actual size of arr given in main is k^2 (k by k matrix)
- so n = k^2    => k = n^(0.5) 
  => T(n) = O(n^(3/2)) ..??

Comment: The call to malloc is almost certainly the bottleneck in this code, so maybe start by fixing that, plus the severe memory leaks, before worrying about algorithm theory.

Comment: If I had a different answer it might be worth showing the math but to this I feel stupid writing an answer of "yes".

Comment: I bet wanted the solution for mergeKArrays() was to merge the arrays in pairs. Then repeat with the `k/2` larger arrays till you have only one. Or to use heap sort on the arrays to merge them all at once.

Comment: @Lundin oh yes, I will defi fix the memory leaks. But what do you mean by "The call to malloc is almost certainly the bottleneck in this code". p.s sorry if this is a dumb question :p

Comment: @dagwood Meaning that the call to malloc is probably some 100 times slower than the rest of the code together.

Comment: @Lundin how did you infer that? also you mentioned i need to fix this..but i need malloc for my array !